# 2001 VW Beetle 02 sensor car will not go over 65mph

Tags: fuel-system, vw, fuel-consumption, o2-sensor

I have a 2001 VW Beetle 2.0 engine  with 171,000 miles on it. I have a check engine light on saying that bank 1 lean. It has been like this for years and I have had no problem with it. Yesterday I discovered that my car in 5th gear will not acclerate any faster than 65 Mph on the highway. My car is a 5 speed manual. When I am in gear 1 for example I can only go 15mph no faster. The tacmeter is a 3,000 and the same in 2-5th gear the tac will not go over 3 grand. I changed the air filter thinking it could not breath. I can smell that my car is getting gas so I know it is not the fuel pump. Then after work today is started working properly again and then I shut the car off and turn it back on the car turns over many times before it will start. Then I drive the car again and it is doing the same thing where it will not go any higher than 3 grand on takometer. Need some help. It also seems that the tail pipe is black the car I think is running to rich... Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Which engine is in your Beetle?

Comment: The Volkswagen has a 2.0 Four-cylinder

Comment: If you can smell that the engine is getting gas, there is a problem. Considering the O2 sensors tell the computer how the engine is using the fuel, why haven't you replaced it? Sounds like this car does not get driven at highway speeds very often. It can be hard on an engine to only be driven for slow, short periods. When was the last time the engine was properly serviced? What other codes are present? You need to get it serviced.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems on 3 vehicles. A Saturn, Ford Escape and GMC Yukon. In every instance I eventually replaced cat converter to fix problem. you should get diagnostic codes then go from there. Hope this helps

Comment: I replaced the cat converted 3years ago... what you think?